# Assumptions in Word Problems (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I just had a small question about assumptions in mathematical word problems. Suppose you are given a calculus problem (related-rates),

"A spherical balloon is inflated with gas at the
rate of 800 cubic centimeters per minute. How fast is the radius of the balloon increasing at the instant the radius is (a) 30 centimeters and (b) 60 centimeters?" (Larson Calculus P 153)

This is a quoted problem from Larson's Calculus 10th Edition.

My question is here:

Why do you assume for example that there is no hole from, which air LEAVES?
Basically, in general, why do you make unstated assumptions for example, there is no air leaving, or the balloon doesnt explode before the radius is (a) 30 cm etc..?

Here is what others say,

Others say it is so you could solve the problem, what do you think?

Comment: Why do you assume, when you walk down the street, that the pavement won't open up and swallow you?

Comment: I think most people wouldn't be filling a balloon if it leaked.  Other reasons for unstated assumptions: (1) If you have to cover every possible contingency, problems would get quite long.  (2) In real life, the problems you get often do not have all assumptions given, and some interpretation is needed.  Having said that, admittedly sometimes problems can be confusing or ambiguous because of the author's unstated assumptions.

Comment: How about this? "The volume of a spherical balloon that is being inflated with gas is increasing at the rate of 800 cubic centimeters per minute. How fast is the radius of the balloon increasing at the instant the radius is (a) 30 centimeters and (b) 60 centimeters, assuming the stated rate of increase of the balloon's volume holds for all radii belonging to some open interval containing 30 and 60?" Note this takes care of what is probably a more significant issue, namely the fact that as the pressure in the balloon increases, the density of the air in the balloon increases.

Comment: "Why do you assume for example that there is no hole from, which air LEAVES?"  For the same reason you don't assume that there is another hole (aside from the one mentioned) from which air enters.

Answer (score 3):

A man walks into a restaurant, orders food, eats, then leaves.

Did the man have to cook his food? 
Did he pay?
Did he sit down?
Did he eat the food he ordered or just eat something else entirely.

Your problem is known in Psychology as the interpretation and application of one's schema.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_(psychology)

Because people are different, they often "fill in the gaps" using different schema than the problem designer had intended. I have experience with this as I used to teach.

If you are ever in doubt. Ask the instructor, or try to imagine the simplest solution possible (no leak or explosions or any other outside problem).

Comment: This is a textbook problem, I cannot ask the author anything. What different "schema" as you call it would be used here? What would you do here anyway?

Comment: I think, in this case, the author just meant "A perfect sphere increases in volume at a rate of 800 cc/min what is the rate of increase of the radius of the sphere at the instant the radius is a) 30cm b) 60cm"

The whole balloon part, I think, is just to add color to the problem. Unfortunately, color to the problem designer sometimes just leads to confusion.

Comment: What is the reason YOU don't assume there is a hole in the ballon?

Comment: I don't assume it because it complicates the problem. That's MY personal reason.

Comment: Thanks amcalde, but how does it COMPLICATE the problem?

Comment: You are considering something that wasn't explicitly mentioned. This means, you are adding some additional constraint or influence on the "answer". That means more things to consider or think about. That is more complicated.

Comment: This is beneficial. So basically it is YOUR choice to complicate the problem or not right? So I CAN choose to not complicate it. 
But what do you think the answer is expecting? The complicated or the uncomplicated? Thanks

Comment: You remind me of Jason, and some other students I've had:

http://www.te-mat.org/images/kouba_2.gif

Comment: I know, I'm sorry. Its my anxiety acting up (OCD).

I was only wondering if everyone accepts this fact as a rather, axiomatic way.

Comment: In general people accept the least complicated interpretation possible.

Comment: True =) I suppose that is what they are taught. Do you agree with me when I say this,

Most people make their life easier, I suppose choosing the simplest way is what people do.

Comment: Yes. My favorite Einstein misquote: "Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler."

Comment: Thank your @amcalde, what you did for me, no one else would have. Can I ask you one LAST question? PLEASE? It can solve my issue COMPLETELY. On tests and homework problems, are they already expecting the EASIEST and the SIMPLEST model? Is there are reason for this or is it just known like that?

Comment: Again: yes. Unless they say "take into account the curvature of the Earth." Then you leave it out. There is a cultural history of interpreting math problems, and for writing them. I know this can be perhaps difficult for some but any new culture can be learned with practice.

Comment: Thanks @amcalde. So I want to conclude everything into one comment. 
You make certain assumptions because you shouldn't complicate the problem. And the MAIN PART - GENERALLY, IT IS ACCEPTED THAT PEOPLE USE THE LEAST COMPLICATED INTERPRETATION. So on tests and homework, they are looking at the simple possible interpretation. 

But wait, is there any reason that tests and homework use the simplest possible interpretation or is it just an ACCEPTED FACT?
I cant believe it, I appreciate your help so so much, I cant honestly thank you enough amcalde, kudos, and cheers to your for being amazing!! :=)

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know that, so I'll retype the comment

Comment: Thanks @amcalde. So I want to conclude everything into one comment. You make certain assumptions because you shouldn't complicate the problem. And the **main point - people generally accept the least complicated model everywhere**. So on tests and homework, they are looking at the simple possible interpretation. **But wait, is there any reason that tests and homework use the simplest possible interpretation or is it just an ACCEPTED FACT?** I cant believe it, **I appreciate your help so so much**, I cant honestly thank you enough amcalde, kudos, and cheers to your for being amazing!! :=)

Comment: Anything please @amcalde?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. That's it.

Comment: I feel as if I am annoying you.... Sorry. But I thought you could help because I thought your comments could potentially solve my problem completely. Especially with the "easiest model" reply. One more comment about my question (in the previous comment) was what I needed. I'm sorry for bugging you =(

Answer (score 1):

Some word problems have unstated assumptions that are *actually* problematic. Here's one of my favorite examples:

> Alice can paint a wall in one hour and Bob can paint it in two. How long will they take to paint it together?

The intended interpretation is that they paint the wall at a constant rate, and that they work together in such a way that you can just add together their painting speeds (like if they're starting at opposite ends of the wall and coming together). This is a somewhat artificial interpretation, and in my opinion not entirely obvious.

I think your balloon problem is a terrible example, though. *Of course* the balloon isn't leaking, that information would have been included in the problem. That's not an ambiguity of the problem statement, that's you making up possible things it could be leaving out. I think (and I'm only speculating) that you might have gotten burned on a few genuinely ambiguous word problems, and it's made you paranoid about all of them. Take a step back, breathe, and remember your common sense.

Comment: Very helpful =) So I will ask you something (you seem extremely smart). Why do YOU yourself interpret this in such a way that there is no leak etc?

Comment: @Aakarsh For the same reason that if somebody gives me an ingredient list for chocolate pudding, I don't assume that they're forgetting to mention the two tablespoons of anchovy paste. It's not like the question is ambiguous, and the phrasing might imply there's a leak. There is absolutely no indication that there's a leak. That's something that you invented entirely.

Comment: So you assume based on no reason? The cake example is good. I suppose it is an "axiom," that you make such assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Too big for a comment:

You can assume that the gas leaks but the leakage is negligible so that the numbers in the problem hold and you can solve it, if it is not negligible then the problem changes.

What you are doing is solving the problem with pen and paper, i.e. theoretically, so we discard unwanted factors (such as temperature, higher temp increases the volume of the gas) but we did not consider it in our problem because for **the problem under consideration** it does not matter.

In real life there can be hundreds of external parameters and also practical limitations like the gas tank is out of gas, will you be able to solve **the problem under consideration** if you assume this situation?

Comment: Why does a hole not matter?
dV/dt = dE/dt - dL/dt [entering - leaving]

Answer (score 1):

Everything has a context.

If that question was asked in the context of a class about balloon physics, you could bet that you would have to use concepts taught therein, such as rubber elasticity, gas densities, shape properties, etc.

Because this is a calculus class, if you knew the material well, you would easily deduce that the problem most likely is asking you to apply a straightforward differential because, if there was a leak, then that would most likely fall into the differential equations realm. Also, you would have most likely run into a similar homework problem.

Comment: Thanks. So from this you know from definition that,
dV/dt = dE/dt - dL/dt [where dE/dt is the entering rate of air, and dL/dt is the leaving rate of air] 

How is this entering the differential equations realm?

ALSO, why did you make certain assumptions before (such as this hole)? What is your personal reason?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly,

For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, the answer is rather simply.

Take a look at,

[**The Cooperative Principle of Communication**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle)

The **Maxim of QUALITY** states one should not mention what is false.

Which is the answer to the question.